# ArrayList concurrency across socket connections

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist

I have an issue. My belief is that is has something to do with concurrency or synchronization of threads, though I cannot put the finger on just what is happening.

Here is my description of the data-flow for our `FriendRequestList` object.

From the client side we send a friend request to another user(worker).
So we send the request and add our own username to their `User.incFriendReq`-list. The instance is an `ArrayList` just for nice-to-have reference.

So now we send the request to the server to receive our own list of friend requests (`FriendRequestList.java`).

So now the problem. If I use this code below the user won't see the friend request before he terminates his connection (logout), which will close the connection. When he logs in, he will only then see the request in his list.

**Server side code:**

... Worker.java ...

```
private Object getFriendRequests() {
    User me = Data.getUser(myUserName);
    if ( me == null ) {
        return new NoSuchUserException(); // Don't worry about it ;)
    }

    return new FriendRequestList(me.getFriendReq());
}
```

... User.java ...

```
private List<String> incFriendReq;

public List<String> getFriendReq() {
    return incFriendReq;
}
```

**Client side**

... Communication.java ...

```
public FriendRequestList getRequests() {
    sendObject(new GetRequests());
    return inputHandler.containsRequests();
}
```

... MessageListener.java ...

```
public void run() {
    ...
    FriendRequestList requests = communication.getRequests();
    update(requestList, requests);
    // Here we have the problem. requests.size is never different from 0
}
```

How ever, if I update `Worker.java` to do this instead:

```
private Object getFriendRequests() {
    User me = Data.getUser(myUserName);
    if ( me == null ) {
        return new NoSuchUserException();
    }
    return new FriendList(me.getFriends().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

The instant the other user requests my friendship, I see the request on my list.
What gives? This sounds to me like the underlying datastructure is not updated, race conditions or something.
But the fix is how I retrieve the data on the server side, by using a stream.

Please someone explain and also how this would be done in Java 7 before streams would solve my, to me, curious problem.

**On a note**

I want to add that the users are placed inside an `LinkedBlockingDeque` and retrieve from the `Data` object, a shared resource for the workers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like returning the `incFriendReq` list directly in `getFriendReq` is one of the sources of your problem. When you use java 8 and stream that list into a new list, you are just making a copy, so there is no useful addition. If this is the case, your server-side code should also work then by using `new ArrayList<>(me.getFriends())`.

I would verify that all accesses to the list are properly synchronized and that you know where and when that list is being mutated.

Comment: The fascinating thing about this code is that while debugging the list I get from the `getFriendReq` is actually of size one. But when I receive the object on the other side it is of size zero.

Comment: It seems to me that the state of your list on the server side is not being properly maintained. The list may be of size zero because a stale copy of the list was still floating around somewhere to be returned but was not the same list as the value you are watching (check the object ID in your debugger to verify) or there is a concurrency issue related to memory visibility that is not exposing mutated data across threads (ensure all accesses to the list are synchronized on the same lock).